# C# - Removing single word in string after certain character

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have string that I would like to remove any word following a "\", whether in the middle or at the end, such as:

```
testing a\determiner checking test one\pronoun
```

desired result:

```
testing a checking test one
```

I have tried a simple regex that removes anything between the backslash and whitespace, but it gives the following result:

```
string input = "testing a\determiner checking test one\pronoun";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\.*\s");
string output = regex.Replace(input, " ");
```

Result:

```
testing a one\pronoun
```

It looks like this regex matches from the backslash until the **last** whitespace in the string. I cannot seem to figure out how to match from the backlash to the **next** whitespace. Also, I am not guaranteed a whitespace at the end, so I would need to handle that. I could continue processing the string and remove any text after the backslash, but I was hoping I could handle both cases with one step.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.*` which match any characters, to `\w*`, which only match word characters.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\\w*");
string output = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

".*" matches zero or more characters of any kind. Consider using "\w+" instead, which matches one or more "word" characters (not including whitespace).

Using "+" instead of "*" would allow a backslash followed by a non-"word" character to remain unmatched. For example, no matches would be found in the sentence "Sometimes I experience \ an uncontrollable compulsion \ to intersperse backslash \ characters throughout my sentences!"

Answer (score 0):

With your current pattern, `.*` tells the parser to be "greedy," that is, to take as much of the string as possible until it hits a space.  Adding a `?` right after that `*` tells it instead to make the capture as small as possible--to stop as soon as it hits the first space.

Next, you want to end at not just a space, but at either a space or the end of the string.  The `$` symbol captures the end of the string, and `|` means or.  Group those together using parentheses and your group collectively tells the parser to stop at either a space or the end of the string.  Your code will look like this:

```
        string input = @"testing a\determiner checking test one\pronoun";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\.*?(\s|$)");
        string output = regex.Replace(input, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this regex (\\[^\s]*)
 (\\[^\s]*)
 1st Capturing group (\\[^\s]*)
 \\ matches the character \ literally
 [^\s]* match a single character not present in the list below
 Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving    back as needed [greedy]
 \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ].
```